# Any different between start rails commands?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
$ RAILS_ENV=dev bundle exec rails c
Loading dev environment (Rails 4.0.4)
[1] pry(main)> exit

$ bundle exec rails c RAILS_ENV=dev
error occur...
```

Any difference between these two rails startup command?

Comment: Yes. One works; the other breaks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they are different as also shown by the result!

`RAILS_ENV=dev bundle exec rails c` will set the variable `RAILS_ENV` to `dev` which becomes available before `bundle exec rails c` is executed.  So, the `bundle exec rails c` will see that variable and use it.

With `bundle exec rails c RAILS_ENV=dev`, `RAILS_ENV=dev` becomes a parameter to `bundle exec rails c`, and because `RAILS_ENV=dev`, the literal is assumed the environment because the first argument to `rails c` if supplied, is the environment.  The error is probably because you do not have an environment by the name `RAILS_ENV=dev`.

To successfully execute the second command you could do:  `bundle exec rails c dev`.